# Which doctor appeared in the most episodes?

Tags: doctor-who

Which incarnation of the doctor had the longest reign?

To measure this we are counting movies as being 2 episodes (equivalent to a two part episode).

Comment: This is easily answered by checking IMDB.

Comment: *"To measure this we are counting movies as being 2 episodes."* I'm not sure this is the best metric. Why not corridors run down? Times the TARDIS landed in an unexpected place? Planets saved from certain doom?

Comment: @dmckee = without knowing anything about Dr. Who, the usual rule of thumb is movie (~1.5-2hrs) is 2x longer than an episode (~45-60mm), so counts for 2 episodes.

Comment: @DVK-in-exile Dr Who is [more complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doctor_Who_serials) than the average show: 263 serials over 35 seasons in 826 episodes, most of which were 25 minutes long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Tom Baker**

`173 episodes, 1974-1981`

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056751/)

The next closest was William Hartnell at 137 episodes.

While David Tennant was in 48 episodes and Matt Smith is closing in at 31.

Comment: You get the check for providing the numbers :D

Answer (score 5):

I believe that would be the [Fourth Doctor](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Fourth_Doctor), played by Tom Baker from 1974 to 1981.

He shows up, uncredited, in [Planet of the Spiders](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_of_the_Spiders)(Season 11) and remains the Doctor until [Logopolis](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Logopolis_%28TV_story%29) (season 18.)

Ignoring any [return appearances](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Dimensions_in_Time) during later Doctor's times, I believe he was the Doctor for 42 full serials, or 172 episodes.  (1 more if you include his appearance in Planet of Spiders, and 1 serial/5 episodes if you count '[Shada](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Shada_%28TV_story%29)', which never aired.)

Comment: How are you counting footage from Shada that appears in The Five Doctors (in the first and last episodes, if I recall).